# Reading protected annotation defined in a class using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have created a class in java as following:

```java
public class TestAnnotations {
    @Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(value=ElementType.FIELD)
    protected @interface Addition
    {
        String location();
    }
}
```

How can I get information about the annotation defined in the class using reflection. To be more specific, I am looking for the information like what is the type of Addition, of course name and its fields in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Class#getDeclaredClasses()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredClasses%28%29) which

> Returns an array of Class objects reflecting all the classes and
>   interfaces declared as members of the class represented by this Class
>   object.

You can then iterate over the array, check that that class is an annotation with [`Class#isAnnotation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAnnotation%28%29).

Example

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?>[] classes = Driver.class.getDeclaredClasses();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(classes));
        for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
            if (clazz.isAnnotation()) {
                Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
                for (Method method : methods) {
                    System.out.println(method);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(value=ElementType.FIELD)
    protected @interface Addition
    {
        String location();
    }
}
```

prints

```
[interface com.spring.Driver$Addition]
public abstract java.lang.String com.spring.Driver$Addition.location()
```